# Parquet read from HDFS and Schema issue

Tags: pyspark, parquet

When i try to read a parquet file from HDFS i get the schema in all mixed case. any way we can convert that to all lower case ?

```
df=spark.read.parquet(hdfs_location)

df.printSchema();
root
|-- RecordType: string (nullable = true)
|-- InvestmtAccnt: string (nullable = true)
|-- InvestmentAccntId: string (nullable = true)
|-- FinanceSummaryID: string (nullable = true)
|-- BusinDate: string (nullable = true)

What i need is like below


root
|-- recordtype: string (nullable = true)
|-- investmtaccnt: string (nullable = true)
|-- investmentaccntid: string (nullable = true)
|-- financesummaryid: string (nullable = true)
|-- busindate: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read the parquet files

```
df=spark.read.parquet(hdfs_location)
```

then use `.toDF` function to create dataframe with all `lower column names`

```
df=df.toDF(*[c.lower() for c in df.columns])
```